# Image cropping windows phone

Tags: c#, image, xaml, windows-phone-7

I want to crop an image in wp7 such that only some part of it appears in an imagebox (or just the 'image' control). I used image.clip, but it actually retains the whole image, and just whitens the 'to-be-cropped' portion. How can i crop the image so that the cropped image is the resultant image?
Note: I am looking for a way in xaml

Comment: Don't think you can, you'll need to pass the image through a transform function and save it locally/in memory and assign to an Image control manually. The only thing you can do is clip an image in XAML.

Comment: Also, are you sure you can't just use clip? I use an EllipseGeometry to clip my images to show portraits of people within a circle and it works on Light/Dark themes without issues, there is no white border/square outside the clip.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me just fine with Light and Dark themes. I'm showing a square image inside an ellipse clip and adding a border around it; it's not showing through.

```
<Grid>
    <Ellipse 
        HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
        VerticalAlignment="Center" 
        Width="78" 
        Height="78" 
        StrokeThickness="5" 
        Stroke=""/>
    <Image 
        HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
        VerticalAlignment="Center" 
        Stretch="UniformToFill" 
        Source="{Binding MediumPhotoUrl}" 
        Width="64" 
        Height="64" >
        <Image.Clip>
            <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="32" RadiusY="32" Center="32,32"/>
        </Image.Clip>
    </Image>
</Grid>
```

Are you sure you're doing clip correctly?

Comment: Doing an ellipse geometry will not make the image ellipse...right? Similarly, the a rectangle geometry doesn't give me a modified rectangle. it just omits the portion. Thanks anyway.

Comment: But if all you need to do is *display* an image that looks like an ellipse... that's what you need right? Is there a reason you need to modify the bitmap to be an ellipse?

Comment: Here's a screenshot of what my app looks like using eclipse geo: http://sdrv.ms/19UYOB9. I believe this is what you're going for, right? If so, the code above is what I use to accomplish it.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the size of the initial image, you can calculate the required transforms, for example:

```
<Image Width="100" Height="100">
  <Image.Clip>
    <!-- Image after clipping takes only a small area in the center -->
    <RectangleGeometry Rect="25,25,50,50"/>
  </Image.Clip>
  <Image.RenderTransform>
    <!-- Transforms Rect(25,25,50,50) into Rect(0,0,100,100) -->
    <TransformGroup>
      <TranslateTransform X="-25" Y="-25"/>
      <ScaleTransform ScaleX="2" ScaleY="2"/>
    </TransformGroup>
  </Image.RenderTransform>
</Image>
```

I don't know a way of doing it automatically (without code behind).